# how to prevent PHP::XSLTProcessor from generating <html> and <body> tags?

Tags: html-parsing, xslt

I am using php `XSLTProcessor` to make transformations of specific parts of XML file that I need to incorporate as  a content inside another HTML document.

The problem is that `XSLTProcessor` always emits code like this:

```
<head>
<body>
[what I need to incorporate]
</body>
</head>
```

I need to prevent it from generating those surrounding tag, how can I do this?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to produce invalid HTML documents and in fact I don't know any way to do it. I always use JS to attach only necessary parts of the result document when using XSLT to transform responses of AJAX requests. Guess it's also an option when using PHP.

Comment: I already built a PHP templating system for my website, I am fetching the XML from another server hence I need to make the transformation server-side due to security reasons, and I do not want to mess up me templates, I just need to incorporate the transformed data into the corresponding placeholders

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a possible solution.

Comment: Is `PHP::XSLTProcessor` injecting those elements after the transformation? Then you should report this bug.

Answer (score 3):

**Have you tried *not* to use the `html` output method?**

I would try:

`<xsl:output method="xml"/>`

If your XSLT processor allows custom XMLWriter classes, you may write such a class that enforces certain lexical forms (such as certain elements not having a short form or writing `<br />` and never `<br></br>`), if such are required.

Comment: Actually there is a method called registerPHPFunctions which enables the ability to use PHP functions as XSLT functions (http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php). I am not sure how to use it yet, but I will give it a try. I got a simple work around  by now which is simply re-parsing the resulted XML as DOM and return the innerHTML of <body> node